# Is Enfys Nest's name meant to be a pun?

Tags: star-wars, names, solo-a-star-wars-story, trope

In *Solo: A Star Wars Story* fans are introduced to a new character named Enfys Nest, a leader of a rebelling pirate group called, the Cloud Riders.

[image: Enfys Nest standing on sand]

Later in the film it is revealed that Enfys

> is a female character!

I have read that the character's aesthetic was a combination of Native American and Samurai, but I was curious about the name, as it sounds/spelled a lot like **"Empty Nest"**, which is term often used referring to when children leave their parents (such as going off to college)...

**Anyways, I was wondering if the character's name Enfys Nest is an intentional pun on "empty nest" or is it at all referring to something else?**

---

**To better explain:**

My interest is in a thematic reference to *'Solo'* and/or the Star Wars franchise as a whole.

> **Authors like to use themes to create a sense of unity or cohesiveness
>   within their work. Some extend themes to** [the names of characters](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/ThemeNaming),
>   often beyond the similarities that would be expected for characters
>   from the same culture or who all speak the same language. When the
>   author does this, you have Theme Naming. For instance, all the female
>   characters will have names of flowers or plants (occasionally the male
>   characters will get Gender Blender Names); all the names start with
>   the same letter or syllable, groups of characters are named after
>   groups of gods, demigods, or mythical heroes. As the list of subtropes
>   demonstrates, there are a lot of possible themes (and that's not all
>   of them, either).

Sometimes characters are named in ways that either play into larger themes of a work and/or may give **a tell** about either the character themselves or the situations they and/or others are in or will become in...

For instance, Darth Vader's name is a tell and a theme, as there is a reveal that he is Luke's and Leia's biological father. Vader is German for "Father", but the word doesn't mean much until one gets to the end of Episode V, but the theme of parentage and/or **different kinds of child and parent relationships**, blood relative or figurative have become apart of many parts of *Star Wars* since this first reveal.

So back to the name Enfys Nest and the phrase Empty Nest. I'm not in anyway suggesting the character is a biological parent, given the characters young age.

What I am wondering about is the concept of empty nest more generally leans towards reminding viewers of **"child and parent relationships"** in *Star Wars*.

As mentioned, the character leads a band of pirates called Cloud-Riders. Cloud-Riders is evocative of the name Skywalker. The Skywalkers in the Saga films are characters that tend to **leave home and/or their parental figures behind**, which is not unlike what Han and Qi'ra try to do at the beginning of *Solo*.

That's not to say that one may not be able to apply empty nest to Enfys Nest, given that this character might come off as a figurative parental figure, being a strong leader of this gang, and later, a reveal that this gang of pirates are not what they seem, as they are

> freedom fighters, who are fighting against the Empire, because of the 
>  Crime Lords persecution of inhabitants and planets with resources,
>  loosing family. ie: empty nests = loss or change of family and the
>  purpose of using this as a more direct theme in *Solo* is about: **the
>  family you choose.**

However, the possibly of applying the phrase to Enfys name may not have come to fruition yet, given that this was *suppose to be a trilogy and now it's unclear if there will future *Solo* films going forward. Many people speculate that she could be another known character's daughter, leading to an irony with the "empty" part, just as "Vader" is ironic in the sense that he wasn't figuratively a [good] father. To further this parallel or juxtaposition, the character mentions a great deal about their mother, but not their father...

Comment: As has been pointed out, it’s “Enfys” and it’s a real name of Welsh origin (meaning “Rainbow”). Although in Wales we pronounce the F with a V sound so it sounds like “Envis”.

Comment: Although interestingly, “Enfys” can be a boy’s or girl’s name so that continues the theme of gender ambiguity of the character.

Comment: @Darren Thanks! Thats interesting to know and I would totally take that  an as an answer, with some source provided.

Comment: Also sorry about forgetting the S. I was having auto correct issues. I fixed it.

Comment: as you wish. Answered.

Comment: @DarthLocke I believe that, currently, your reasoning is simply too loose. She is not a mother, so she has no empty nest syndrome in the traditional sense. She has a group of people she leads, so if she does have a nest, it isn't empty. She left home, but so do 99% of characters in adventure stories. The name "Enfys" is not a whole lot like "empty," other than being a short word that starts with E. I'm not saying that your question is necessarily invalid, but your hypothesis seems very weak on every point. You need to bring in at least something that feels solid.

Comment: @DarthLocke I didn't think you were necessarily saying that she is a literal mother.  It's just that, if you're going with the *figurative mother to her clan* logic, then her nest isn't empty.

Comment: @DarthLocke I'm not trying to argue about this, just pointing out a possible reason the rating of the inquiry is low, and how you could invite more research into the question, rather than getting "I doubt it" answers (which the logic behind your question invites at the moment).  I actually don't see at all how what I said made your point better - but, if it did, consider updating the question with it in mind.  Or not - your choice, of course :)

Comment: I totally understand and appreciate the discussion. And I think Darren's and Patrick's answer are perfectly satisfying for me. And that's fine, if I am wrong. I was only explaining what I meant.by asking :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Probably not. But there may be some deliberate ambiguity as to her gender, as the name *Enfys* ([name of Welsh origin meaning “rainbow”](https://welshgirlsnames.co.uk/enfys/)) can be used for both boys and girls.

Answer (score 4):

### Almost certainly not

Her name is actually *[Enfys Nest](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Enfys_Nest)* (pronounced "Enfis" as noted by [@PatrickWynne](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/195601/is-enfys-nests-name-meant-to-be-a-pun/195602?noredirect=1#comment536929_195602)) and she is only 18 in *Solo*, barely old enough to have kids (of which there is no evidence) let enough suffer from [Empty Nest Syndrome](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empty_nest_syndrome).

---

<sup>(the original version of the question omitted the "s", calling her "Enfy" thereby leading to some confusion)</sup>

Comment: @DarthLocke - It seems like a *real reach*

Comment: Could be, but doesn't mean it is not a valid question. Questions are asked here to find out there validity, no? To me, it's just such a close sounding phrase. The writers could chose whatever they wanted.

Comment: Even Han Solo's name, especially "Solo" had been debated if it was thematic to being "alone" or "single" (and the irony of that name) for a long time and now we know that it was even more literal than that in terms of how the character gets this surname in universe. So I don't think I'm over reaching, even if it turns out to be false. Things like this is how writers establish themes.

Comment: Vader is German for father. so there's that too.

Comment: *Enfys* is pronounced "enfis", not in any way that rhymes with *empty*, so given that fact and that the name is *Enfy**s*** rather than *Enfy*, I just don't see how it would make any sense to have a connection in meaning.

Comment: @PatrickWynne if either you or Darren want to make than an answer with a source, I'll gladly take it!

Answer (score 0):

We've cleared up the meaning of Enfys, rainbow, meanwhile nobody seems to have mentioned the name Nest. Nest is also a Welsh girl's name. There's a well known Nest, Nest ferch Rhys, in Welsh history, her story is well worth a look.

The idea that the name invokes the parent - child relationship theme in the films is probably not as relevant, I'm sure there are other ideas that the name Enfys Nest brings to the character and the film.

Comment: You might just want to [edit] this slightly so it's clear what your answer is to the main question here: Is Enfys Nest's name meant to be a pun? As this is it reads more as a comment or continuation of the discussion rather than a complete contained answer which it should really be. This isn't a normal discussion forum but a question and answer site. You might want to take the [tour].